# What is the error calculating the sum of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to determine if $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n-1}{4^n}$$ converges, in which case I must also find its sum, or diverges. This is my approach:

$i$) $$\frac{2^n-1}{4^n}=\frac{2^n}{4^n}-\frac{1}{4^n}=\frac{2^n}{2^{2n}}-\frac{1}{4^n}=\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{4^n}$$

Then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n-1}{4^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{4^n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4^n}$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{16}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-1}$$

$ii$) We found our series can be written as the difference of two geometric series with $|r|<1$, and the solution is

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{16}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{\frac{1}{16}}{1-\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{5}{12}$$

I have given this series to an online series calculator, and it claims the result is not $\frac{5}{12}$ but $\frac{2}{3}$, and yet I can not find the mistake in my procedure. Can anyone point it out to me?

EDIT: Please remember, I'm asking more than "what is the right way to solve this problem"; I'm asking precisely what was the mistake I made. Correlated, but not the same.

Comment: Shouldn't the factors $\frac 1 4$ and $\frac 1 {16}$ be $\frac 1 2$ and $\frac 1 4$, respectively?

Comment: @MartinR look at the comment on Doug's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error in algebra:

You have
$a^n = a^2 a^{n-1}
$
for $a = \frac12$ and
$\frac14$.

It should be
$a^n = a\cdot a^{n-1}
$.

$a^2 a^{n-1}
=a^{n+1}$.

Comment: Oh dear mother of god this is what I missed. Thanks Marty.

Comment: You are welcome. I've made my share of errors too.

Answer (score 2):

My short solution:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n-1}{4^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n-\frac{1}{4^n}\right]=1-\frac13=\frac 23$$

PS: I have applied a criteria of a series geometric when $|x|<1$. See the link http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html formula number (9).

Comment: Perhaps you should  mention the formula $\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge 1}x^n=\frac x{1-x}$. $\;(+1)$

Comment: @Bernard Very kind Bernard I have solved this series using the link http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html. See the edit. I am not fast to solve and to write. :-(

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} k^n = \frac {k}{1-k}\\
\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac {1}{2})^n = \frac {\frac 12}{1-\frac 12} = 1\\
\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac {1}{4})^n = \frac {\frac 14}{1-\frac 14} = \frac {1}{3}\\
\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac {1}{2})^n - \sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac {1}{4})^n = \frac 23$

Comment: I upvote you for your fast answer :-).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still don't see why stating that $(\frac{1}{2})^n=(\frac{1}{2})^2*(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}=\frac{1}{4}*(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$ and then solving the geometric series with $a=\frac{1}{4}$ and $r=\frac{1}{2}$ is wrong, what is the error in this?

Comment: I'm using the identity $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ar^{n-1}=\frac{a}{1-r}$ if $|r|<1$.

Comment: $\frac {1}{2}^n = \frac 12 (\frac 12)^{n-1}$ not $\frac {1}{2}^n = (\frac 12)^2 (\frac 12)^{n-1}$